# How to access raw data from multiple microphones

Tags: audio

I want to play with raw audio data. But i want to do this with multiple microphones. What are the things i will need?

I have figured out that i probably need a mixer to get all the mics data.
I need help understanding the basic set up (software (programming language/libraries,drivers, etc) and hardware (mixer with USB connection)).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what will you be using to access that data (e.g. programming language), what hardware are you using, etc...

Comment: @akostadinov that is precisely my question! I want to know what my options are.

Comment: There are a lot of options - hardware and software. What do you want exactly to do? And OS of choice is also very important. Also many people can give you part of the information. But you need to be more specific what you ultimately want to achieve.

Comment: Do you need to do this with programming or could you record audio files (using any of a multitude of available programs), then process them however you wish? Saving to uncompressed PCM audio formats such as .wav would let you load in (essentially) raw recorded data from the microphones.